# Ubuntu: Can't connect to the wireless network

Tags: wireless, networking, vmware, adapter

I can't connect to the wireless network on Ubuntu. I'm using VMware to use Ubuntu on Windows. I can't add the wireless network adapter to the Virtual machine settings.

I think that might be the reason Ubuntu is not able to identify the wireless network adapter on its list of hardware.

If anyone knows why Ubuntu doesn't recognize the wireless adapter please reply to this post. Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure the device status is connected under VM --> Settings --> Network Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I have no idea what's causing this, the question is vague.  However it may be that the card you're using in broadcom? If so, I can help out there for sure.

One thing I would recommend is not to use VM simply because you lose a lot of functionality. If you're only trying it, or running a quick thing, you may want to consider a dual boot - it's always good to have a backup plan, also you could just use a live install on a USB stick, you get 4 GB and for small things, you're set. Otherwise I would install alongside windows, or use the live install.

Answer (score 0):

Try Connecting with a [Zydas USB 2.0 wlan adapter](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Technologies-802-11g-Wireless-Network-Adapter/dp/B000CC3ZFS/ref=sr_1_40?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1342652847&sr=1-40).

It works for me, it cost £6.95 from amazon